# Using Clique decision to solve Clique optimization

Tags: algorithms, graphs, optimization

How can you perform the clique decision algorithm fewer than $ O(n) $ times to solve clique optimization?

I'm not sure if my approach is right but this is my thought process: you would pick vertices in a graph and see if they form a clique, then keep picking more vertices until you have the max possible clique.

I'm not sure how it can be done less than $ O(n) $ times.

I can imagine an undirected graph such as:

[image: undirected graph]

where $ \{A, B, C\} $ and $ \{B, C, D\} $ would be cliques. The number of vertices is 4, and the number of vertices in the cliques is 3, which is $ n - 1 $. Would this count as being done in less than $ O(n) $ times, or is this the wrong approach to this problem?

Comment: $n - 1$ is not less than $O(n)$. A function $f(n)$ is less than $O(n)$ if $f(n)/n \rightarrow 0$. In your case, $(n-1)/n \rightarrow 1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would use binary search.  Start with the lower bound being 3 and the upper bound $n$, where $n$ is the number of vertices.  Call your clique decision oracle with a $k$ value halfway between the two bounds.  If it answers "yes", move your lower bound to $k + 1$.  If it answers "no", move your upper bound down to $k - 1$.  Repeat until you have found the largest $k$ value the oracle answers "yes" to.  It should take $O(\log n)$ calls to the oracle.

Comment: How did you decide that the lower bound should be 3?

Comment: @deezy If the graph has any edges at all, then it contains a 2-clique, so I didn't see any point in using the oracle for that. But 2 would work as well as 3.